# Telnet Server Service Doesn't Work

Tags: networking, lan, services, telnet

I want to be a Telnet Server, but i couldn't troubleshooting that why other computer on my LAN couldn't connect to me. I went these same steps on other computers but there were no problems to connect them and i can telnet to them.

1) i turned `Telnet Client` and `Telnet Server` features from "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features"

2) then i enabled `TELNET` service from Services.msc and set that to Automatic.

3) also i enabled Telnet Server option from "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Firewal\Advanced settings (Inbound Rules)" and allowed the connection.

4) so i started Telnet Server service from CMD using "net start telnet"

then i tried to connect my Telnet Server from other LAN Computers. but it said:

```
Connecting To 192.168.1.103...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:
 Connect failed
```

How can i Fix this problem ?

 I'm using Windows 7 and Avast! Anti-virus and Avast! internet security.

 note: I did these same steps on another LAN computers , so i could connect to them.

Comment: can you try `netstat -n -l` in `cmd` to see if you listen on port 23?

Comment: The parameter " -l " not working. i can connect to my telnet server using this computer, but others can not connect ! also i scanned from other computers and i find out that 23 port is not Actived (or allowed) .

Comment: I strongly suggest *not* using Telnet, even if it is only in the LAN – the Windows Telnet server is also not maintained anymore, so third-party alternatives like [WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) may be more reliable as well.

Comment: @grawity, Security is not important on my LAN Network. because all of computers are in my control.

Comment: @AmirrezA_Nasiri: I was not talking only about security.